# @typescript-eslint/typedef enable call-signature

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have recently upgraded my angular application to use eslint instead of tslint.

I'm now struggling to enable `call-signature typedef`.

So, before, I had this:

```json
"typedef": [
    true,
    ...,
    "call-signature"
]
```

But in Eslint, I can't find the equivalent. When looking through [their git page](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/typedef.md#options), I see this:

```
type Options = {
  arrayDestructuring?: boolean;
  arrowParameter?: boolean;
  memberVariableDeclaration?: boolean;
  objectDestructuring?: boolean;
  parameter?: boolean;
  propertyDeclaration?: boolean;
  variableDeclaration?: boolean;
  variableDeclarationIgnoreFunction?: boolean;
};
```

How can I enable call-signature ?

Doing this is not triggering any warning, despite setting everything to true:

```js
public someMethod() {}
```

Here is my tslint config:

```json
"@typescript-eslint/typedef": [
    "warn",
    {
        "arrayDestructuring": true,
        "arrowParameter": true,
        "memberVariableDeclaration": true,
        "objectDestructuring": true,
        "parameter": true,
        "propertyDeclaration": true,
        "variableDeclaration": true,
        "variableDeclarationIgnoreFunction": true
    }
]
```

I tried to add `call-signature` but it didn't help.

Comment: Then I think it is that ESLint just doesn't support this. You can report your problem to their issue tracker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, you have to use this rule to enforce type definitions.

```
"@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": [
      "error",
      {
        "allowExpressions": true
      }
    ]
```

You can refer here:
https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-function-return-type.md

This will enforce the same return type definition ruleset of TSLint on functions, arrow functions, and class methods.